# debugging in Vue. Quick and dirty way to console.dir() a reactive variable?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this malfunctioning code within a Vue component that's caused by `_errors` being `undefined` in my `data`, at least when the page is loading.

```
  data: function () {
     var temp = {
        show_debug : false
        ,password_changed_flag : false
        ,_errors : this.$store.state.form01._errors  || {}
     }

    var data = Object.assign({}, this.$store.state.form01.data, temp);

    //this is the part I am struggling with:
    console.log("data:");
    console.dir(data);


    return data;
  },
```

This isn't however about what I am doing wrong, it's about how to easily `console.dir(data)` Vue's reactive objects.

I.e. how can I print out a simple nested object, minus the getters and setters?  And take a **snapshot in time** of that object.

i.e. `_errors` seems to be present now, but I'd like to only display the state of the object at the completion of the `data` function, not track subsequent changes.

What I am currently getting in Firefox and Chrome is instead the following:

[image]

Comment: console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(thing)))

Comment: Btw, for what it's worth, I suspect it was a glitch with my data attribute starting with '_'.  I saw some issues in Vue's github about leading underscores, though some of those have been closed in the past.  More a bug than a feature - it's intended to work, rather being a special case - seems like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(thing)))
```

Won't work on the Vue itself, but for data properties should be fine.

Comment: Txs.  Works like a charm.  I'll leave the question open for now, in case somehow comes up with a better idea, but will accept if not.

Comment: @hackel True, if you have a circular reference in your object structure.

Answer (score 1):

As of Vue3 it seems [toRaw](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#toraw) can serve that purpose as well.

> Returns the raw, original object of a Vue-created proxy.

Yes, I had looked [older issues](https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/292) too.

```
import {reactive, computed,ref, toRaw} from 'vue'
...

// this will be a reactive Vue object
const data_from_store = store.state[form_name].data;
console.dir({data_from_store});

// and this is an object I can pass as POST data or console.dir
const raw_data = toRaw(store.state[form_name].data);
console.dir({raw_data :  raw_data});
```

##### console.dir from store/reactive:

```
    
Object { data_from_store: Proxy }
​
data_from_store: Proxy { <target>: {…}, <handler>: {…} }
​​
<target>: Object { run_option: "validate_only", rdbname: "HCM92ORP", fieldfilter_all: false, … }
​​
<handler>: Object { get: get(target, key, receiver), set: set(target, key, value, receiver), deleteProperty: deleteProperty(target, key)
, … }
​
```

##### console.dir after toRaw

```
Object { run_option: "validate_only", celery_task_id: null, rdbname: "HCM92ORP", fieldfilter_all: false, fieldfilter_keys: true, fieldfilter_lastupd: false, fieldfilter_effdt: true, fieldfilter_effstatus: false, fieldfilter_objectownerid: false, fieldfilter_descr: false, … }
​
celery_task_id: null
​
fieldfilter_all: false
...​
```

An image does a better job though:

[image]

Comment: OP, you should accept this as the correct answer for the benefit of everyone arriving here in the future. the currently accepted answer isn't the way people should solve this problem.

Comment: I'll bear that in mind, but not before retrying it *next time* I need to do this kind of debugging.  Just to make sure it works as I said.  Or else if a few more people confirm it worked for them.